# PHP update function not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, content-management-system

I have this function, its purpose is to update a post. I have another function that pulls the data from the database and displays it between `<form>` tags and the action will direct to a update.php file which includes the following:

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");

$obj = new data_handler; 
$obj->update_post($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Then this is run:

```
public function update_post($id) {  
  try {
    $sql = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE Content SET Title=?, Body=? WHERE id=?");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $_POST['title']);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $_POST['body']);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $id);
    $sql->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

This is the function that pulls the content to edit:

```
public function display_selected ($id) {
    $sql = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id= '$id'");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo $row['Body'];
    }
}
```

This is the form:

```
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" size="105" name="title"></input>
        <textarea name="body"><?php $obj = new data_handler; $obj->display_selected($_GET['id']); ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
```

I get no errors/exceptions/warnings, I can go through the whole process, but it does not change anything.

Comment: you're posting to update.php but looking for `$_GET['id']` .. that isn't set anywhere..

Comment: @DannyHearnah $_GET is usally set by the webserver....

Comment: and does `$obj = new data_handler; ` really works? I supposed it must be `$obj = new data_handler();`

Comment: @mercsen I thought of that myself, and tried it on another function, it works with and without the parentheses.

Comment: @mercsen `new data_handler` is valid and works

Comment: @mercsen lol, i understand that :-) however you show me where there is a GET request in any of the code that is being sent to update.php.. non on update.php form, i'd expect it to be `update.php?id=1` OR the `id` should be sent as a POST request in the form, as a hidden field with the name id

Comment: see my answer for more information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

change

```
$obj->update_post($_GET['id']);
```

to

```
$obj->update_post($_POST['id']);
```

and add this to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
```

*It's worth noting: input tags are self closing, so you don't need  at the end.*

**Option 2**

change

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="update.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Nice! I tested a bit more and found out I'm not getting an ID so it doesn't really know what to change. You already got a solution! Thanks a lot!